# trying to retrieve data from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with records of some students that looks like this:
table = score
id   name               score
1    Michael Smith        67
2    Lois Brown           72
3    Kate Smith           53
4    Nick Ross            56

What I want to do is use my dropdown list which contains the names of the students to retrieve the information about the students and display them one at a time. for example, if I click on Nick Ross in my dropdown list, I expect it to display 4, Nick Ross and 56 in a table form, but instead I get it to display a blank page. kindly help. here are my scripts

```
<html>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<form method = "POST" action = "students.php" >
<select name="students">
  <option>Select a name:</option>
  <option>Michael Smith</option>
  <option>Lois Brown</option>
  <option>Kate Smith</option>
  <option>Nick Ross</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type = "submit" name "submit" value ="Process">
</form>

<br>


</body>
</html>
```

students.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','school');
if(!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $students = $_POST['students'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, FROM score WHERE students = $students");

    echo "<table align='center'  width='340px' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    </tr>";

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
} 

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: You have mixed `mysql` and `mysqli ` - mysql_error

Comment: a good place to start with PHP is to turn on error reporting. I think you should remove the comma after the * in your query. Might be another error but give that a shot

Comment: i have removed the comma after the *, but still nothing. however when i tested this on wamp, I get an error message saying:                                   Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\wamp\

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the id you want to get from the database as value. In your html put in the `<option>` tag the value attribute as following:

`<option value="1">Michael Smith</option>
<option value="2">Lois Brown</option>`

And probably you will need to change your sql query to match the change. I would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM score WHERE id = $student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display record of student you can use simple hyper link with id of that student insted of form and when user click that link simply get id from url and fetch record from database.

E.g

`<a href="students.php?id=1">Michael Smith</a>`

Then in student page just get id

```
<?php
   $id = $_GET['id'];

  //Then use simple select query to fetch record from database

   SELECT * FROM score WHERE id = $id;
?>
```

And if you want to use Drop-down, I would prefer you to use Ajax with same method as I described above.